# Start hbase in CDH5 VM in standalone mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How can I start my Hbase in Standalone mode in a CDH5 VM. In CDH3 VM, I used to run

> 'sudo sh start-hbase.sh'

in the below path:

> /usr/lib/hbase/bin

But, I can only see '*start-hbase.cmd*' in the above path in CDH5 VM. Please let me know how can I start my HBase instance by invoking the above '.cmd' file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following command to start a service in CDH5 VM

> sudo service <(service name)> start

eg:

> sudo service zookeeper-server start

or we can also go to the path

> /etc/init.d

and execute the same command as above!